# error when using task queue

Tags: google-app-engine, email, task-queue

I have a google app engine.
When i add a task to task queue to send email. I have this error:

Request failed because URL requires user login. For requests invoked within App Engine (offline requests like Task Queue, or webhooks like XMPP and Incoming Mail), the URL must require admin login (or no login).

my command is

taskqueue.add(url='/mypage/operation/task', params={'key': operation.key()}

Please help me to fix it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

This specifically refers to which handler in your `app.yaml` matches the task worker URL. It can specify no login requirement or `login: admin`, but not `login: required`.

This is a sanity check to ensure you understand the context in which tasks run. Tasks are permitted to bypass handlers decorated with `login: admin`, but when they run, they will not have any user in context. `users.get_current_user()` and `users.is_current_user_admin()` won't work within the context of task execution, so putting tasks behind a `login: required` handler doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your url setup it hard to say, but it appears /mypage/operation/task requires a user to be logged in to call it,  but something that is sent to the task queue is gonna be called behind the scenes without a user logged in.

either remove the login requirement from that url, or make it an admin required url